# How can I use Process.PriorityClass on some Processes that run under the SYSTEM account and which throw the exception "Access is denied"?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a requirement to display the Priority Category of all Processes running on the machine via a WinForms application. My Winforms application runs as Administrator set in the application manifest. I'm currently using `Process.PriorityClass` to obtain the Priority Category and it works fine for most processes; but for some processes like csrss, smss, Registry, System, Wininit etcetera, while using`Process.PriorityClass` on these, it throws an exception: *"Access is denied"* which occurs at `System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId, Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)`. I notice that these processes run under the SYSTEM account. I have also seen that this exception does not get thrown on all processes running under the SYSTEM account.

Currently, when this exception is thrown while accessing `Process.PriorityClass` for any process, I work around it to get the `PriorityClass` for these by a P/INVOKE call to `GetPriorityClass()` in `kernel32.dll` which works well enough but I dislike the switching to unmanaged code.

My question is: Is there a way for me to use `Process.PriorityClass` to obtain the Priority Category on these Processes that run under the SYSTEM account and which currently throw the exception?

Comment: `Process.PriorityClass` already calls `GetPriorityClass()` and accesses the Process calling `OpenProcess()`, setting `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` as access right, the only one available to call `GetPriorityClass()`. PInvoking directly should give you the same Access Denied exception -- In any case, can you show your code? More specifically, how do you get the Process Handle to call `GetPriorityClass()` without exceptions, while trying to open, e.g., the System Process?

Comment: The thing is that for these Processes's that throw an exception, while using P/Invoke, I have to pass PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION as access rights while using OpenProcess(). Using PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION throws an exception.

Comment: Then there's no problem. You're P/Invoking in any case, directly or using `Process.PriorityClass`: same call to `GetPriorityClass()` (if you're using .Net Framework).

Comment: I mean, is this a matter of *portability*? That's why you're trying to avoid a Win32 function call? Have you tested .Net 5 or .Net Core 3.1?

Comment: I think I know what the cause of the problem is. See <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights>this</a>:  . At the end of that page there is a section with the heading: Protected Processes. I seem to be getting the exception on these protected processes.

Comment: Messed up the link in my previous comment. This is it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights